# Update com divisao PHP e MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, mysqli, tabela-banco-de-dados

Como faço um `UPDATE` para todos os usuários de um banco de dados?

Por exemplo:

```
UPDATE usuarios 
SET juros=investimento + investimento * 30 /100
WHERE id='89'
```

O banco pegará os dados de investimentos e adicionará 30%, porém se eu tirar o `WHERE` para adicionar esse valor para todos os outros usuarios aparece o seguinte erro:

Mensagem do MySQL: Documentação

> #1292 - Truncado errado DOUBLE valor: ''

Comment: Remover o "Where" para alterar todos os registros da tabela funciona sim, este erro está relacionado a outra coisa. Um exemplo que retorna esse erro é comparar valores de tipos incompátiveis, como Double e String, você tem certeza de que estes tipos estão corretos?

Comment: Como que está essa coluna no banco de dados ?

Comment: algum `investimento` deve estar em branco; pode checar se é isso mesmo?